# ElasticBeanstalk: storing a bullet proof docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I built a Docker image that runs in AWS.

In the Dockerfile I put some commands that download some sources from some websites, so obviously if these sites for some reason are down spawning a new node running that image will fail.

How can I be safe against this risk?

Is there a way of storing a prebuilt docker container, that can be deployed to a node when needed (e.g. when an application needs to scale up) without running the Dockerfile every time?

Comment: Hello, did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes, thanks, docker push worked as expected

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `docker push` command. When you build your `Dockerfile`, docker creates an image for later run containers. Check `docker images`. Then these images can be uploaded to a registry. Docker Hub provides a free repository per user so you can upload the image there.

Also you can use the container service as @willian-paixao said.

Docker also have a very handy command called `docker save`. It will save your image in a TAR file. And then you can upload it to S3. When you need the image again, just download it from S3, and make a `docker load`. With this approach you have your image store and don't need to use a registry.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

After you build an image, docker wont rebuild it until the dockerfile changes, so new containers will keep using the original image and wont pull from remote websites.

You can also add your Dockerfile to sites like [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) which will build your image and allow you to pull the pre-build image down to your machines without having to rebuild them.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using AWS, I will mention Amazon's services.

You'll create your own registry on [EC2 Container Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/).
As @chris-tanner mentioned, you are going to upload your Dockerfile and EC2 will store, build and make it ready to deploy. Features as scale, migration and monitoring are also available.

Access EC2 documentation for getting started.